# Run time error 91 when not able to find value in excel sheet using vba code

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim Filesfolder As String

Sub datacollection()

x = 2

'Filesfolder = InputBox("Please enter the folder address where files are store")

'LoopThroughFiles

For a = 1 To Workbooks("Book5.xlsm").Sheets("Mapping").Range("H5000").End(xlUp).Row

Filename = Workbooks("Book5.xlsm").Sheets("Mapping").Range("H" & a).Value

Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\amardeep-singh\Desktop\Lean Automation and Templates\CCR\Raw\" & Filename)

For b = 1 To Workbooks("Book5.xlsm").Sheets("Mapping").Range("c5000").End(xlUp).Row

Carfamily = Workbooks("Book5.xlsm").Sheets("Mapping").Range("c" & b).Value



For i = 1 To 17

Va = Workbooks("Book5.xlsm").Sheets("Mapping").Range("E" & i).Value


'Va = Workbooks("Book5.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, i)).Value

Range("A1:D5000").Find(What:=Carfamily).Select

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlToRight).End(xlToRight).End(xlToRight)).Select

Range(Selection, Selection).UnMerge


On Error GoTo errorhandler

Range(Selection, Selection).Find(What:=Va).Select


Rowy = Range(Selection, Selection).Row
Coly = Range(Selection, Selection).Column

y = 4

For j = 1 To 13


Workbooks("Book5.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, y).Value = Cells(Rowy, Coly).Offset(0, 1).Value
y = y + 1
Coly = Coly + 1
Next j


Workbooks("Book5.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Filename
Workbooks("Book5.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Carfamily
Workbooks("Book5.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Va


errorhandler: x = x + 1

Next i
Next b
Next a

End Sub
```

Comment: Getting error at this statement  "Range(Selection, Selection).Find(What:=Va).Select"

Comment: Please add a description of what you tried and the error that you get directly in the description of the questions.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `Range(Selection, Selection).Find(What:=Va)` returns `Nothing` if the value was not found. So nothing to .Select, hence the error.
Check the result of Find before select it:

```
Set f = Selection.Find(What:=Va)
If Not f Is Nothing Then f.Select
```

Side note: `Range(Selection, Selection)` = `Selection` in this case.
I also recommend that you pay attention to [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)